# Getting a chapter number value for comparing

Tags: chapters, programming

I'm trying to compare a chapter number like this:

```
\newcounter{exerciseChapterCounter}
\newcounter{exerciseChapterCounter}
\newcounter{exerciseQuestionCounter}
\setcounter{exerciseChapterCounter}{1}
\setcounter{exerciseQuestionCounter}{0}
   
\newcommand{\exercise}{
    \if \value{chapter} > \exerciseChapterCounter 
    \stepcounter{exerciseChapterCounter}
    \setcounter{exerciseQuestionCounter}{1}  
\else
    \stepcounter{exerciseQuestionCounter}
\fi

\section*{Exercise \arabic{exerciseChapterCounter}-\arabic{exerciseQuestionCounter}}
}
```

It doesn't seem like the \if section is being hit, though.

Comment: You probably need `\ifnum` instead of `\if`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated my code to use `\ifnum`:

```
\newcounter{exerciseChapterCounter}
\newcounter{exerciseQuestionCounter}
\setcounter{exerciseChapterCounter}{1}
\setcounter{exerciseQuestionCounter}{0}
   
\newcommand{\exercise}{

    \ifnum \value{chapter}>\value{exerciseChapterCounter}
    \stepcounter{exerciseChapterCounter}
    \setcounter{exerciseQuestionCounter}{1} 
\else
    \stepcounter{exerciseQuestionCounter}
\fi
```

This works. Thanks to Phelype Oleinik for your help.